# How to get all the xml tags and replace the tags by new name using java

Tags: java, xml

I need to get all the xml tag names (not value) and replace some of the tags name by my new name

For finding the xml tag names i used the below code but it is showing error on "element.getnode()" line

```
   File input = new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\admin\\Desktop\\xml\\Data Entry.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document doc = (Document) dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(input);
   doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    System.out.println("Root element " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    NodeList nodeList=doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
       System.out.println("nodeList"+nodeList);

    for (int i=0; i<nodeList.getLength(); i++)
    {
    // Get element
    Element element = (Element)nodeList.item(i);
// getting error in this print statement    
   System.out.println(element.getNodeName());
    }
    }
```

Here am trying to get all the tagname and replace that by new name.

Here's the XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?> 
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Data%20Entry.xsd" generated="2014-02-12T14:35:47"> 
    <Data_x0020_Entry> 
        <ID>1004</ID>
        <User>006Parthiban</User>
        <Data_x0020_Entry_x0020_Date>2013-12-26T00:00:00</Data_x0020_Entry_x0020_Date>
        <Publication>Daily Thanthi</Publication>
        <Edition>CE City Edition</Edition> 
        <Location>Bangalore</Location> 
        <Print_x0020_Date>2013-12-06T00:00:00</Print_x0020_Date>
        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber> 
    </Data_x0020_Entry> 
</dataroot>
```

Comment: post the sample xml file.3

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Data%20Entry.xsd" generated="2014-02-12T14:35:47">
<Data_x0020_Entry>
<ID>1004</ID>
<User>006Parthiban</User>
<Data_x0020_Entry_x0020_Date>2013-12-26T00:00:00</Data_x0020_Entry_x0020_Date>
<Publication>Daily Thanthi</Publication>
<Edition>CE City Edition</Edition>
<Location>Bangalore</Location>
<Print_x0020_Date>2013-12-06T00:00:00</Print_x0020_Date>
<PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
</Data_x0020_Entry>
</dataroot>

Comment: dude there is no element.getnode()  in above code ??

Comment: Its in in the print statement and in that line only it shows error like "cannot find method getNodeName"

Answer (score 0):

i think u  imported from  wrong package.change the imports like below

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
```

while dealing with xml using the DOM parser u need to import from `org.w3c.dom` package only

Comment: update question with excepted xml ..that means present tag-->tagnames after changing

Comment: need to change <Data_x0020_Entry_x0020_Date> by <DataEntryDate> and also i have some unicode characters too..   
<Data_x0020_Entry>
<ID>1004</ID>
<User>006Parthiban</User>
<DataEntryDate>2013-12-26T00:00:00</DataEntryDate>
<Publication>Daily Thanthi</Publication>
<Edition>CE City Edition</Edition>
<Location>Bangalore</Location>
<PrintDate>2013-12-06T00:00:00</PrintDate>
<PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
<PageType>03 முதல் பக்க செய்திகள்</PageType>
<ArticleType>01 செய்தி</ArticleType>
<Data_x0020_Entry>

Comment: you added some more tags and just renaming the tag names ..u added PageType and ArticleType..what is dis ?

Comment: Its a long xml...but for your reference i added some tags...i have more than 100 tags but for unicode format i just added some more tags

Comment: u can do one thing ..read the input xml file using domparser and create another xml file using that ..

Comment: i tried rename node but its not working...  doc.renameNode(doc, "Data_x0020_Entry_x0020_Date", "DataEntryDate");

Comment: no u can't do like that directly...follow this http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/...read input file and make another copy of it by changing the node names